# How to fix missing values in appropriate position in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this...

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 4))
dat$X1 <- seq(1,10)
dat$X2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
dat$X3 <- c(1)
dat$X4 <- c("c(2,3,4)","c(1,2,4)","c(1,2,3,4)","c(1,2,3)","c(1,2,3,4)",
            "c(1,2,3,4)","c(2,3,4)","c(1,2,3)","c(1,2,3,4)","c(1,2,3,4)")
colnames(dat) <- c("Subject","Session","other","option")
```

Then I use tidyr to fix it up...

```
library(tidyr)
dat <- separate(dat, option, sep = ",", into = paste0("option.", 1:4))
colnames(dat) <- c("Subject","Session","other","pk1","pk2","pk3","pk4")
dat$pk1 <- gsub("c", "", dat$pk1)
dat$pk1 <- gsub("[()]", "", dat$pk1)
dat$pk3 <- gsub("[()]", "", dat$pk3)
```

I want it to look like this...

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 4))
dat$X1 <- seq(1,10)
dat$X2 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
dat$X3 <- c(1)
dat$X4 <- c("c(NA,2,3,4)","c(1,2,NA,4)","c(1,2,3,4)","c(1,2,3,NA)","c(1,2,3,4)",
            "c(1,2,3,4)","c(NA,2,3,4)","c(1,2,3,NA)","c(1,2,3,4)","c(1,2,3,4)")
colnames(dat) <- c("Subject","Session","other","option")
dat <- separate(dat, option, sep = ",", into = paste0("option.", 1:4))
colnames(dat) <- c("Subject","Session","other","pk1","pk2","pk3","pk4")
dat$pk1 <- gsub("c", "", dat$pk1)
dat$pk1 <- gsub("[()]", "", dat$pk1)
dat$pk4 <- gsub("[()]", "", dat$pk4)
dat
#    Subject Session other pk1 pk2 pk3 pk4
# 1        1       1     1  NA   2   3   4
# 2        2       1     1   1   2  NA   4
# 3        3       1     1   1   2   3   4
# 4        4       1     1   1   2   3  NA
# 5        5       2     1   1   2   3   4
# 6        6       2     1   1   2   3   4
# 7        7       2     1  NA   2   3   4
# 8        8       2     1   1   2   3  NA
# 9        9       3     1   1   2   3   4
# 10      10       3     1   1   2   3   4
```

How would I go about adding missing values to the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove everything but digits and commas, then separate into rows, then pivot wider. The two `arrange()`s put the columns and rows in the same order as your example output.

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(option = str_remove_all(option, "[^\\d,]")) %>% 
  separate_rows(option, sep = ",") %>% 
  arrange(option) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = option, values_from = option, names_prefix = "pk") %>% 
  arrange(Subject)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
   Subject Session other pk1   pk2   pk3   pk4  
     <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1       1       1     1 NA    2     3     4    
 2       2       1     1 1     2     NA    4    
 3       3       1     1 1     2     3     4    
 4       4       1     1 1     2     3     NA   
 5       5       2     1 1     2     3     4    
 6       6       2     1 1     2     3     4    
 7       7       2     1 NA    2     3     4    
 8       8       2     1 1     2     3     NA   
 9       9       3     1 1     2     3     4    
10      10       3     1 1     2     3     4
```

That said, I am curious where the values in `dat$X4` initially came from. If you have a list of numeric vectors that you deparsed into character somewhere upstream, there may be a better approach.

Comment: That worked but now I have a new problem. I have a 5th column that needs to be separated but the numbers are not in sequence. How can I split the fifth column to match the na values from the other columns?

Comment: @jc2525 I think you should start a follow-up question.